# random file selection program

Tags: php, file, random

I am trying to create a php file that finds a random file in the same directory as the .php file, grab the name of that file and return it. i.e, it would return something like "text45.txt" as the output. (not the text inside the file just the file name and extension)

I need it the choose a random file but while choosing a random file in the directory chosen, stop "results.php" from becoming chosen as this is the file used for grabbing a random file.

```php
<?php
$files = glob(realpath('./') . '/*.*');
$file = array_rand($files);
echo basename($files[$file]);
?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

for select file randomly

```
function random_files($array_files_list, $no_of_select ){
    if( count($array_files_list) <= $no_of_select ){
        return array_rand($array_files_list, $no_of_select);
    }else{
        return array_rand($array_files_list, count($array_files_list)-1 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need filter files, you can use [scandir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) instead of glob to get file names in a directory. here is the solution

```
// current directory
$dir = getcwd();
// get all files in directory
$files = scandir($dir);

//filter only files and remove 'results.php' file
$file_arr = array_filter($files, function($file){
     return is_file($file) && $file != "results.php";
});

$file_name = array_rand($file_arr);
echo $file_arr[$file_name];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php

$files = glob(realpath('./') . '/*.*');

// Search the array for the file results.php and return its key
$unwanted_file = array_search(realpath('./results.php'),$files);

//Then remove it from the array
unset($files[$unwanted_file]);

$file = array_rand($files);

echo basename($files[$file]);

?>
```

Comment: sadly this didnt work, http://arilis.win/api/google/getrandompurchase/request.php you can see it still shows the "request.php" file.

Comment: @Arilis I just noticed that the filename of your live version is request.php not results.php, maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `basename(__FILE__)` to find the name of currently executing script and remove it from the array of files.

```
<?php
$files = glob(realpath('./') . '/*.*');

// Ensure the current script is not chosen.
$currentFile = basename(__FILE__);
if (array_key_exists($currentFile, $files)) {
    unset($files[$currentFile]);
}

$file = array_rand($files);

echo basename($files[$file]);
```

**Update**

The above code won't work as the `$key` in `$files` is numeric. We need to loop over the files and check the `basename` of each one. If it is found, unset it. There are more efficient ways to handle this but this should be OK for a small(ish) directory.

```
<?php
$files = glob(realpath('./') . '/*.*');

// Ensure the current script is not chosen.
$currentFile = basename(__FILE__);
foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
    if (basename($file) === $currentFile) {
        unset($files[$key]);
    }
}

$randomFile = array_rand($files);

echo basename($files[$randomFile]);
```

Comment: sadly it shows nothing as the result. http://arilis.win/api/google/getrandompurchase/request.php <-- as seen there

Comment: Change `return` to `echo`.